# Set activefilter using Include

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I'm using Devexpress Gridcontrol.
I'm trying to create a filter.

```
 Dim l as List(of Integer)

 Mygridview.ActiveFilterString="l.contains([id])

 MyGridview.ActiveFilterEnabled=True
```

But this is not working.The grid is not filtered.
What can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

From the expression `l.contains([id])` I see that you have tried to use VB.net syntax to create the filter expression. But the [ColumnView.ActiveFilterString](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.ActiveFilterString.property) property accepts only the valid filter expression with using the special syntax. In short, a filter expression is a formula (or a set of formulas) that specifies how data should be filtered. Each expression contains three parts:

- **data field** whose values should be filtered;
- a filtering **value** that should be compared to records stored in the data field;
- an **operator** that compares data field values with a filtering value.

> GridView1.ActiveFilterString = "[ID] = 1 OR [ID] = 3

To learn more, see the [Criteria Language Syntax](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/4928/DevExpress-Data-Library/Criteria-Language-Syntax) article.